# lsof: no pwd entry for UID

Tags: solaris, command, lsof

I'm trying to run command lsof |grep services on my Solaris 10 to find any processes that have big files which are using up the disk space but i got a bunch of lines saying:

lsof: no pwd entry for UID 105

I looked at /etc/passwd but there's no user with UID 105 (I think this user was deleted).

What is the lsof line above indicating?

Answer (score 10):

> I looked at /etc/passwd but there's no user with UID 105 (I think this user was deleted).

That's what the `lsof` output is indicating. There's a process running owned by UID 105, but when it tried to lookup the username, there's no entry for that UID in `/etc/passwd`. Most likely the process was started before the user was deleted, and has been running ever since.

Comment: ... or the user created a setuid program somewhere other than his home directory, and somebody ran it.

Comment: and how can i find the process running by UID 105? I think it's the reason that causes the main problem where df reports 97% disk usage but du only reports half of it.

Comment: @Tom `ps -U 105` and `ps -u 105` for UID and EUID, respectively

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I did but they both show me unknown user 105.

Comment: @Tom That's not what I get on Linux; I don't have a Solaris box to test on. Can you just `ps aux` and `grep` that?

Comment: Can also be due to processes running in a container, like docker, that have that UID. The warning can be silenced with the -w option.

Comment: Oh thanks. Yeah, that was exactly the reasion it was giving this message, the Docker Container users appear to me as "?". Solved it with -w parameter.

Answer (score 5):

This message is a warning from `lsof` that there are one or more processes running under the named UID that have no entry in the user database (typically `/etc/passwd`). UIDs from 100000 are used typically for LXC container processes, so running these will likely trigger the message.

As it's a warning it can be suppressed with `-w` (no warnings):

```
lsof -w [<other args…>]
```